# Is it possible to find all integer solutions?

Tags: linear-programming

[image]

I wanna get all integer solutions in a limited time, is it possible?

Comment: Are the `p_i >= 0`?

Comment: yes, ````p_i>0````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a linear, integer [constraint satisfaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction) problem, which can be solved efficiently by [OR Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization)' CP-SAT. I've modified [their example](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver#all_solutions) to solve your problem in Python:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

class VarArraySolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
    """Print intermediate solutions."""

    def __init__(self, variables):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self.__variables = variables
        self.__solution_count = 0

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        self.__solution_count += 1
        for v in self.__variables:
            print('%s=%i' % (v, self.Value(v)), end=' ')
        print()

    def solution_count(self):
        return self.__solution_count

def SearchForAllSolutionsSampleSat():
    """Showcases calling the solver to search for all solutions."""
    # Creates the model.
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    p = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    ceq = 30
    cgeq = 2

    N = len(p)

    # Creates the variables
    x = [model.NewIntVar(0, 100, f'x{i}') for i in range(N)]

    # Create the constraints.
    model.Add(sum([xi*pi for xi, pi in zip(x, p)]) == ceq)
    model.Add(sum(x) >= cgeq)

    # Create a solver and solve.
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solution_printer = VarArraySolutionPrinter(x)
    status = solver.SearchForAllSolutions(model, solution_printer)

    print('Status = %s' % solver.StatusName(status))
    print('Number of solutions found: %i' % solution_printer.solution_count())


SearchForAllSolutionsSampleSat()
```

Comment: it works when size of p is small, what if size of p is a bit larger?(>2000) I want to figure out x which always be zero in all solutions

Comment: @Jerome That's a whole different question than the one you asked initially. It's pretty easy to see that any x associated with a p > 30 will have to be zero. Other than that I don't think there is an easy way to find out which x will allways be zero. The program runs on my machine with 2000 p values no problem.

Comment: PS: Are you sure you want all solutions with that many p values? Are you sure you don't want to solve this as a knapsack problem? In other words, with a certain value for each item and selecting the best solution rather than all solutions?

Comment: what is the range of you 2000 p? in my case, all 2000 p<30

Comment: Are the p values also integers?

Comment: p values are decimal like 3.14, i change all to integer multiply by 100, and 30 to 3000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205668/discussion-between-chthonicdaemon-and-jerome).